# 32-bit fixed point arithmetic 1x1 does not equal 1

Tags: c, fixed-point

I'm implementing 32-bit signed integer fixed-point arithmetic. The scale is from 1 to -1, with `INT32_MAX` corresponding to 1. I'm not sure whether to make `INT32_MIN` or `-INT32_MAX` correspond to -1, but that's an aside for now.

I've made some operations to multiply and round, as follows:

```cpp
#define mul(a, b) ((int64_t)(a) * (b))
```

```cpp
#define round(x) (int32_t)((x + (1 << 30)) >> 31)
```

The product of two numbers can then be found using `round(mul(a, b))`.

The issue comes up when I check the identity.
The main problem is that 1x1 is not 1. It's `INT32_MAX-1`. That's obviously not desired as I would like bit-accuracy. I suppose this would affect other nearby numbers so the fix isn't a case of just adding 1 if the operands are both `INT32_MAX`.
Additionally, -1x-1 is not -1, 1x-1 is not -1, and -1x-1=-1. So none of the identities hold up.

Is there a simple fix to this, or is this just a symptom of using fixed point arithmetic?

Comment: `x + (1 << 30)` is very likely to cause an integer overflow bug. How do you protect against that?

Comment: `x` is always assumed to be the product of two `int32_t`s, so it shouldn't overflow

Comment: " I'm not sure whether to make `INT32_MIN` or `-INT32_MAX` correspond to `-1`". It must be `-INT32_MAX` otherwise you will have a different 'scale' for positive and negative numbers and won't be able to do any operations that involve a positive and a negative number.

Comment: In your 1x1 example after multiplying `2147483647 * 2147483647` you need to divide by `2147483647` to realign. You can't do that by shifting. You can only to that if the 'scale' is a power of 2, so that `1` is represented by, for example, 2**30. Then the product of two positive vlaues could be `((int64_t)a * b) >> 30` with some rounding before shifting if you like.

Comment: For negative values, you'll need to figure out the final sign, negate any negative values, do the multiplication, rounding and then the shift, and negate the product if necessary. An inline function will be better than a macro.

Comment: The simple fix is to **use a scale factor that is a power of 2**. (Weather Vane already pointed that out, but it bears repeating, with emphasis.) So you have two choices: 1) Accept a range of `[-1, +1)` using `2**31` as the scale factor, or 2) use a range of `[-2, +2)` with a scale factor of `2**30`. Those are [half-open intervals as defined here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology)

Comment: I'd agree with others (that the scale should be a power of 2); but I'd go one step further and say that it is NOT fixed point maths unless the scale is a power of 2. The entire idea (and definition of) "fixed point" is that some bits are before the decimal point and some are after the decimal point, and the decimal point is at a fixed position between these groups of bits.

Comment: @Brendan: Fixed-point can use any base. Money is commonly represented in fixed-point decimal, such as $3.45. Color intensities are commonly represented with 0-255 representing intensities from 0 to 1. The problem in this case is that using `INT_MAX` as the base is likely a poor computational choice, not that the terminology is flawed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Their terminology is "non-standard" (and their base is a poor computational choice). None of the examples you've provided have ever been called "fixed point" by anyone (least of all programmers).

Comment: @Brendan: Money has been represented in fixed-point since forever: [“MONEY can stored fixed-point numbers”](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=types-moneyps-data-type), [“Currency variables … fixed-point number”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/currency-data-type). And fixed-point is essentially just scaling, and this is common terminology: [“A value of a fixed-point data type is essentially an integer that is scaled by an implicit specific factor…”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)

Comment: @base12masterrace `1 << 30` --> `(int32_t)1 << 30` to allow correct functionality when `int` is 16-bit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Money has been represented as "dollars and cents" (or "with 2 digits after the decimal point") since whichever country it is changed from the currency they used before; but nobody has ever called it "fixed point". "Fixed point" has a more specific meaning (and is in contrast to "floating point", which is also binary).  The correct word you're looking for is "scaled".

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Note that for your examples; the first is using BCD so the fixed point is between (groups of 4) bits; and Wikipedia is using "between digits" and not "any scaling factor" in its introduction before using binary for everything else (but are using "scaling factor" to make it easier to describe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In its general form, a fixed-point format represents a number *x* as an integer *x*•*s*. Commonly, *s* is a power of some base *b*, s = *b*<sup>*p*</sup>. For example, we might store a number of dollars *x* as *x*•100, so $3.45 might be stored as 345. Here we can easily see why this is called a “fixed-point” format: The stored number conceptually has decimal point inserted as a fixed position, in this case two to the left of the rightmost digit: “345” is conceptually “3.45”. (This may also be called a radix point rather than a decimal point, allowing for cases when the base *b* is not ten. And *p* specifies where the radix-point is inserted, *p* base-*b* digits from the right.)

If you make `INT_MAX` represent 1, then you are implicitly saying *s* = `INT_MAX`. (And, since `INT_MAX` is not a power of any other integer, we have *b* = `INT_MAX` and *p* = 1.) Then −1 must be represented by −1•`INT_MAX` = `-INT_MAX`. It would not be represented by `INT_MIN` (except in archaic C implementations where `INT_MIN` = `-INT_MAX`).

Given *s* = `INT_MAX`, shifting by 31 bits is not a correct way to implementation multiplication. Given two numbers *x* and *y* with representations *a* and *b*, the representation of *xy* is computed by multiplying the representations *a* and *b* and dividing by *s*:

- *a* represents *x*, so *a* = *xs*.
- *b* represents *y*, so *b* = *ys*.
- Then *ab*/*s* = *xsys*/*s* = *xys*, and *xys* represents *xy*.

Shifting by 31 divides by 2<sup>31</sup>, so that is not the same as dividing by `INT_MAX`. Also, division is generally slow in hardware. You may be better off choosing *s* = 2<sup>30</sup> instead of `INT_MAX`. Then you could shift by 30 bits.

When calculating *ab*/*s*, we often want to round. Adding ½*s* to the product before dividing is one method of rounding, but it is likely not what you want for negative products. You may want to consider adding −½*s* if the product is negative.

Comment: Since an arithmetic right shift is equivalent to division by 2**n with rounding to *negative infinity*, a round-to-nearest fixed-point multiplication would in fact always *add* 2**(n-1) prior to the right shift. This assumes that C's right-shift operator, when applied to a signed integer type, results in an arithmetic right shift, which is *not* guaranteed by the ISO-C standard but is the case for all C compilers I am familiar with.